# Mysql Row Value Swap

Tags: mysql

I want to swap the 2 rows values like below

```
+----+--------+------+-------+
| id | p_name | p_no | ms_no |
+----+--------+------+-------+
|  1 | S_1    |    1 |     1 |
|  2 | S_2    |    2 |     1 |
|  3 | S_3    |    3 |     2 |
|  4 | S_4    |    4 |     2 |
+----+--------+------+-------+
```

I want to swap **ms_no** 1 to 2 where **p_no** 1, 3 result should be like below.

```
+----+--------+------+-------+
| id | p_name | p_no | ms_no |
+----+--------+------+-------+
|  1 | S_1    |    1 |     2 |
|  2 | S_2    |    2 |     1 |
|  3 | S_3    |    3 |     1 |
|  4 | S_4    |    4 |     2 |
+----+--------+------+-------+
```

I have try some ways, but no success.

Comment: *I want to swap ms_no 1 to 2 where p_no 1, 3 result should be like below.* What is operation's external parameters? `p_no IN (1, 3)` only?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tablename t1, tablename t2
SET t1.ms_no = t2.ms_no,
    t2.ms_no = t1.ms_no 
WHERE t1.p_no = 1
  AND t2.p_no = 3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=728edc409aec2ef41bb1c79e1a4f30c0)

In SET clause ALL values on the right side of `=` are initial values, not ones calculated on previous rows of this SET.

PS. Rather then user-defined variables.

Comment: *In SET clause ALL values on the right side of = are initial values* not for MySql. Check this:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and this:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc945f42b134c46c34160ff16e043e12

Comment: @forpas https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cb38b7cb47f9582100e26ffad616f9e and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c86881c44b51253d62ef3fbe0d6b3313

Comment: Check in the documentation link I posted in my previous comment the part *...This behavior differs from standard SQL....*. Your code works though and I suspect that it works because it is a multi-table update.

Comment: @forpas *it works because it is a multi-table update.* o_O of course... The documentation does not treat single-table and multi-table UPDATE as different query options for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `where` clause to find the appropriate rows (`p_no` is 1 or 3 and `ms_no` is 1 or 2), and a `case` expression to swap between them:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    ms_no = CASE ms_no WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
WHERE  ms_no IN (1, 2) AND p_no IN (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.p_no = 1 AND t2.p_no = 3 OR
       t1.p_no = 3 AND t2.p_no = 1
SET
    ms_no = t2.ms_no;
```

This approach brings the swapped record into line for each of the `p_no = 1` and `p_no = 3` records in the original table.  Then, we only need to overwrite the `ms_no` value with the value from the joined table.

Comment: Why would you complicate it so much, can be done easily without join

Comment: ... so says a user who didn't even post an answer `:-)`

Comment: I was posting an answer using IF but another user already posed it using Case so no need to add same answers again